# Summing the amount of times a word appears in a list, and putting the value and word in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

I have an assignment where I have to create a module with a list of functions, where a string is written to a file. The part I'm stuck at is where I have to take the amount of times a word appears in the input string, and add it to a dictionary. The key of the dictionary will be the word, and the value will be the amount of times the word appears in the string.

```
def word_freq_dict(): # function to count the amount of times a word is in the input string
   file = open("data_file.txt", 'r')
   readFile = file.read() #reads file
   words = readFile.split() #splits string into words, puts each word as an element in a list
```

The other functions work, I made sure of it. What I have so far is taking the words and putting them into a list. I want to sum the amount of times each word appears in the list, and add it to a dictionary with the word being the key and the amount of times it appears being the value. This function does not return anything.

Comment: Look up the Python documentation for the **Counter** subtype of dictionary.

Comment: So, the code you showed right now simply gets your list of words. What have you tried next to try to get your counts. Maybe you were close and just need a hint. Can you show your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to do this:

```
word_count = {}
for word in words:
    word_count[word] = word_count.get(word,0) + 1
```

By using 0 as default in the dict.get() function, it returns 0 when the word first appears. If the word is already in the dictionary, it returns the current value for the key. Then you just add 1 in each iteration.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I knew I had to use a for loop but had no idea how to implement it.